# Usage of @Stateless and @Transactional on a POJO class - when and why?

Tags: design-patterns, jakarta-ee, transactions, cdi, stateless-session-bean

I have a developer in my team who uses both of the annotations @Stateless and @Transactional on POJO classes that do not need any of these to work correctly.
Example:

```
@Stateless
@Transactional(Transactional.TxType.REQUIRED)

public class ObjektAnlegenService {

    public Home setImagesToHome(Home home, ImagesUploadHelper imgUpldHelper) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(home, "Home is Null!");
        Objects.requireNonNull(imgUpldHelper, "ImagesUploadHelper is Null!");
        String mainImage = null;
        for (Image savedImage : imgUpldHelper.getImagesSaved()) {
            if (savedImage.isMainImage()) {
                mainImage = savedImage.getSimpleFileName();
            }
            savedImage.setHome(home);
        }
        home.setHomeImages(imgUpldHelper.getImagesSaved());
        home.setMainImageTabl(mainImage);
        return home;
    }

    public String[] getPlzOrtDetails(String plzOrtInput) {
    
        int indexOfComma = plzOrtInput.indexOf(Constants.COMMA);
        indexOfComma = indexOfComma == -1 ? plzOrtInput.length() : indexOfComma;
        
        String[] plzOrt = PlzOrtUtils.getPlzOrt(plzOrtInput.substring(0, indexOfComma));
        return plzOrt;
    }
}
```

My questions:

1.) @Transactional only makes sence, when the POJO class (or its methods) shall work with a transactional datasource, such as database  or a transactional web-service. Otherwise it only adds a load to the server, right?

2.) @Stateless only makes sence when we want the JEE server container to manage the CDI (context and dependency injection) of the POJO class. But @Stateless adds an additional load to the JEE Server, because  @Stateless beans are insantiated, pooled and kept in JNDI, right?

Then: if a POJO can exist and work as a singleton (as is the case with ObjektAnlegenService above), isn't it better to design it as a singleton, instead of a @Stateless?

Answer (score 2):

`@Stateless` marks the class as a stateless session EJB. As such it lives and is managed by the EJB container (so, right, pools, JNDI etc). Session EJBs are also visible to the CDI container and available for injection with `@Inject`, but it is the EJB container that is responsible for them. So, this is not exactly as you say "

So, to answer the question whether you want the class annotated with `@Stateless`, you need to decide whether you need those services. If not, `@ApplicationScoped` will do.

`@Transactional` instructs the *CDI container* to activate transactions for this component. If you decide that this component needs to be an EJB, remember that the EJB container activates transactions by default to session EJBs. So, the extra `@Transactional` annotation is redundant.

You may add transaction demarcation annotations in every method to explicitly state that it needs to be transactional. I would prefer to demarcate the transactions at the top level of the business layer and only where needed, but this is only *my* opinion.

**EDIT-CLARIFICATION:** *Would a singleton POJO be better?* By *singleton POJO* I assume you mean annotating the class with [javax.inject.Singleton](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/inject/Singleton.html), not [javax.ejb.Singleton](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ejb/Singleton.html), which is an EJB. If so, bear in mind that `javax.inject.Singleton` defines a *pseudo-scope* and as such the bean is not eligible for interception. Since the `@Transactional` annotation works by defining an interceptor, it would not work for `@javax.inject.Singleton` beans. That is why I mentioned `@ApplicationScoped` above. This is effectively a singleton (as in the singleton pattern), but is eligible for interception, so all expected facilities of the CDI container apply.

Comment: OK, but that dioes not anser my question: In the case above, these annotations only add a server load - a singleton POJO would it be better?

Comment: See the edit-clarification about singleton and `@ApplicationScoped`. In short, if you do not need the facilities of the EJB container, then defining it as `@ApplicationScoped` is preferred over `@Singleton` because it can use a proxy and all the facilities of the CDI container.

Comment: Sorry, I meant just a simple Singleton class (not the @Singleton annotation), i.e. a class, whose object is not managed by the container nor by the CDI, just a Simple POJO

Comment: Ah, then you don't get the goodies of the container: DI (you don't need it now, so that is a weak argument), other components that are managed by a container cannot inject this class, they will have to access the singleton - this would make tests trickier, interception (e.g. no `@Transactional`). So, I would say no, if your architecture is based around a container, use it for all components (except perhaps the dummiest ones, like `StringUtils`)

Comment: Ok, great! So, you mean I should not care that this may create an additional load to the server? Better managed by the server than manged by me?

Comment: Well - let's say yes unless you have a compelling reason not to. By the way, generally CDI is much lighter (regarding load to the server).